# problem in parsing JSON response in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios4

i am getting json data from [this link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=delhi&destination=noida&waypoints=&sensor=true)

now i want data from "html_instructions": part

```
NSDictionary *result = [stringtext JSONValue];
NSLog(@"here");
NSArray *resultarr = [result objectForKey:@"routes"];
NSString *string;

for(NSDictionary *di in resultarr){
    NSLog(@"for loop");
    string = [[di objectForKey:@"legs"] objectForKey:@"steps"];
}
```

but after printing "for loop" in console it is throwing an exception

```
2011-05-20 16:16:26.997 speedymap[759:207] -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x62a7d60

2011-05-20 16:16:26.999 speedymap[759:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x62a7d60'
```

please help me
i want html_instructiuons field value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=delhi&destination=noida&waypoints=&sensor=true

Check the viewer and set the values accordingly. [di objectForKey:@"legs"] returns an array. the first object of that array is a dictionary which has the key steps. But that too returns another array.

Answer (score 3):

Check if `resultarr`  and `di` really contains anything or not.

```
NSDictionary *result = [stringtext JSONValue];
NSLog(@"here");
NSArray *resultarr = [result objectForKey:@"routes"];
CFShow(resultarr);
NSString *string;

for(NSDictionary *di in resultarr){
    CFShow(di);
    NSLog(@"for loop");
    NSArray *tempArr = [[di objectForKey:@"legs"] objectForKey:@"steps"];
}
```

Comment: Thanx karim thats wat i am doing now. :)